# Query posts intersecting tags and categories

Tags: wp-query, categories, query, tags

if I have category 'catname' and tag 'tagname'

is it possible to visit for example site.ext/catname/tagname and query all posts that are contained in specific category 'catname' and specific tag 'tagname'?

I hope that the question is clear.

Please let me know,
thanks